# How to fix an issue with a view of my website's mobile version?

Tags: wordpress

My website is https://www.jobsfrf.com/.
I'm currently facing issues with the website view on mobile, it only loads correctly when scrolling up and down with the view.
For example this URL - https://www.jobsfrf.com/employee-registration/.
When I access the registration/login view, it loads when you are moving through the page only. Content is not loading properly.
Website is developed with WordPress.
Any idea what could cause such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `Ultimate Member` plugin in your website. I inspected `Employee registration` screen and found `opacity` is set to the form's parent element.

```
<div class="um um-register um-138 uimob500" style="opacity: 1;">
```

In the style attribute, which is set using jQuery for `Fade-in` effect I think. See if there's any option in the plugin's page in your WordPress Admin Dashboard to remove that effect or you could remove that by manually adding below CSS:

```
.um-register {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: No, I mean my full website and not just Employee registration page

Comment: Maybe delay in loading content or the Theme you are using has fade effect enabled on scrolling for the first time. You could show preloader until all the components in the page are loaded.

Comment: No, I tried preloader but nothing happened.